# Programatic way to do linear referencing in ArcGIS

Tags: c#, arcgis, arcobjects

I am working on a custom ArcGIS Desktop tool project and I would like to implement an automated linear referencing feature in it. To make a long story short, I would like to display problematic segments along a route and show the severity by using a color code (say green, yellow, red, etc.). I know this is a pretty common scenario and have come to understand that the "right way" of accomplishing this task is to create a linear event table which will allow me to assign different codes to certain route segments. Some of my colleagues know how to do it manually but I can't seem to find any way to replicate this programaticaly.

The current tool is written in C# and already performs all the needed calculations to determine the problematic areas. The problem mainly is that I don't know where to start since I don't know a lot about ArcObjects. Any code sample or suggestion is welcome (C# is preferred but C++, VB and others will surely help me anyway).

EDIT :

I'm trying to use the MakeRouteEventLayer tool but can't seem to get the different pre-conditions met. The routes are hosted on an SDE server. So far, I am establishing a connection this way :

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IPropertySet pConnectionProperties = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.PropertySet();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory pWorkspaceFactory;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace pWorkspace;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Location.ILocatorManager pLocatorManager;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Location.IDatabaseLocatorWorkspace pDatabaseLocatorWorkspace;

pConnectionProperties.SetProperty("server", "xxxx");
pConnectionProperties.SetProperty("instance", "yyyy");
pConnectionProperties.SetProperty("database", "zzzz");
pConnectionProperties.SetProperty("AUTHENTICATION_MODE", "OSA");
pConnectionProperties.SetProperty("version", "dbo.DEFAULT");

pWorkspaceFactory = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory();
pWorkspace = pWorkspaceFactory.Open(pConnectionProperties, 0);
pLocatorManager = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Location.LocatorManager();
pDatabaseLocatorWorkspace = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Location.IDatabaseLocatorWorkspace)pLocatorManager.GetLocatorWorkspace(pWorkspace);
```

Now I am stuck trying to prepare everything for MakeRouteEventLayer's [constructor](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/shared/geoprocessing/linear_referencing_tools/make_route_event_layer_linear_referencing_.htm). I can't seem to find how i'm supposed to get the *Feature Layer* to pass as the **Input Route Features**. Also, I don't understand how to create an event table properly. I can't seem to find any exemple relating to what I am trying to accomplish aside from [this one](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/com/Gp_ToolRef/linear_referencing_tools/make_route_event_layer_linear_referencing_.htm) which I don't understand since it isn't documented/commented and the datatypes are not mentionned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what it is you want to do. If you want to get Linear Referencing values or manipulate them directly in a feature class that already has linear referencing defined, that's pretty straight forward.

IFeatureClass fc = ....;
IFeature feature = fc.GetFeature(...);
[IMSegmentation3](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriGeometry/IMSegmentation3.htm) seg = (IMSegmentation3)feature;
... blah ...

If you need to create a Feature class with linear referencing, you should start witht he "Geoprocessing" tools in the ArcToolbox. If the out-of-the-box tools can do most of what you need, this will minimize your coding.

I would *strongly* recommend trying to figure what you need to do with ArcMap if at all possible... then backing out the ArcObjects.

1. [Linear Referencing API](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriLocation/Location_overview.htm#LinearRef)
2. [Linear Referencing Toolbox](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/java/Gp_ToolRef/linear_referencing_toolbox/understanding_linear_referencing.htm)
3. [Understanding Linear Referencing](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/java/Gp_ToolRef/linear_referencing_toolbox/understanding_linear_referencing.htm)